# copymemory VB6/VBA to VB.net Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: vb.net, encryption, vb6, visual-studio-2017, aes

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to get the following to work or replace in order to make work:

Module1:

```
Private oTest                   As Class1
Private InitDone                As Boolean
Private Map1(0 To 63)           As Byte
Private Map2(0 To 127)          As Byte

#If VBA7 Then
  Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#Else
  Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Declare Sub CopyMemoryByref Lib "Kernel32.dll" & _
                    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef dest As Integer, ByRef & _
                    source As Integer, ByVal numBytes As Integer)

Private Declare Function VarPtr Lib "vb40032.dll" & _
                         Alias "VarPtr" (lpObject As Integer) As Long

Public Function EncryptData(ByRef bytMessage() As Byte, ByRef bytPassword() As Byte) As Byte()
        Dim bytKey(31) As Byte
        Dim bytIn() As Byte
        Dim bytOut() As Byte
        Dim bytTemp(31) As Byte
        Dim lCount, lLength As Integer
        Dim lEncodedLength, lPosition As Integer
        Dim bytLen(3) As Byte

        If Not IsInitialized(bytMessage) Then Exit Function
        If Not IsInitialized(bytPassword) Then Exit Function

        For lCount = 0 To UBound(bytPassword)
            bytKey(lCount) = bytPassword(lCount) : If lCount = 31 Then Exit For
        Next lCount

        gentables()
        gkey(8, 8, bytKey)
        lLength = UBound(bytMessage) + 1 : lEncodedLength = lLength + 4

        If lEncodedLength Mod 32 <> 0 Then lEncodedLength = lEncodedLength + 32 - (lEncodedLength Mod 32)

        ReDim bytIn(lEncodedLength - 1) : ReDim bytOut(lEncodedLength - 1)

        Try
            CopyMemory(VarPtr(bytIn(0)), VarPtr(lLength), 4)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        For lCount = 0 To lEncodedLength - 1 Step 32
           CopyMemory(VarPtr(bytTemp(0)), VarPtr(bytIn(lCount)), 32)
           Encrypt(bytTemp)
           CopyMemory(VarPtr(bytOut(lCount)), VarPtr(bytTemp(0)), 32)
        Next lCount
End Function
```

UserForm:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
    Dim sTemp, sPassword As String

    sTemp = "this is a test"
    Debug.Print("       To encrypt: " & sTemp)

    sPassword = "blk@vjdii:5@fAB5"
    Debug.Print(StrReverse(sPassword))

    sPassword = Str2Hex(strEncrypt(sPassword, StrReverse(sPassword)))
    Debug.Print("       Secret key: " & sPassword)

    sTemp = Str2Hex(strEncrypt(sTemp, sPassword))
    Debug.Print("          Encrypt: " & sTemp)

    sTemp = Base64EncodeString(sTemp)
    Debug.Print("Encrypt w/ Base64: " & sTemp)

    sTemp = Base64DecodeString(sTemp)
    Debug.Print("Decrypt w/ Base64: " & sTemp)

    sTemp = Hex2Str(sTemp)
    Debug.Print("          Decrypt: " & strDecrypt(sTemp, sPassword))
End Sub

 This code works just fine when using it within the VBA excel code. This is the VB6 output:
```

> To encrypt: this is a test
>
> Secret key: F050C1C2B61E8DCC349DC498D9993F8D11330F12D9E0071B4B83D172FEBE5AED
>
> Encrypt: F899ABA853D21B20F889CFD18BB42C472187B4E1CF613139370313DFD8A492DE
>
> Encrypt w/ Base64:
>
> Rjg5OUFCQTg1M0QyMUIyMEY4ODlDRkQxOEJCNDJDNDcyMTg3QjRFMUNGNjEzMTM5MzcwMzEzREZEOEE
>   0OTJERQ==
>
> Decrypt w/ Base64: F899ABA853D21B20F889CFD18BB42C472187B4E1CF613139370313DFD8A492DE
>
> Decrypt: this is a test

However, when converting it over to .net I get the error of:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

on the line **CopyMemory(VarPtr(bytIn(0)), VarPtr(lLength), 4)**.

How can I re-write this in order for it to work so both VB.net and VB6 can share the code base in order to encrypt/decrypt string messages back and forth?

Comment: That is the underlying SEH exception that the VB4 runtime uses to raise an Err.  You of course have no hope of interpreting that exception correctly in a .NET program.  Or of using VarPtr, that dependency on vb40032.dll must be retired.  Chasing a "common code base" is a fallacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Array.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx) Method in VB.NET. VB.NET has a completely different memory model than VB6. You cannot apply VB6 functions from VB6 DLLs in VB.NET! .NET has its own encryption system. See: [System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Array.Copy(bytTemp, 0, bytIn, lCount, 32)
```

VB.NET is not just a VB7. VB.NET is a completely new language with a completely new type system, new libraries, new DLL and EXE structures, new runtime infrastructure, new ... (well almost everything is new)

As Hans Passant already hinted at: it is almost impossble to have a common code base for VB6 and VB.NET

Comment: I get the error **Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.** once I change the code to yours.

Comment: The desination array must be long enough to receive the data. It will not resize automatically. `Public Shared Sub Copy (
 sourceArray As Array,
 sourceIndex As Integer,
 destinationArray As Array,
 destinationIndex As Integer,
 length As Integer
)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function StrToByte(ByRef strInput As String) As Byte()
    Dim lPntr As Integer
    Dim bTmp() As Byte
    Dim bArray() As Byte

    If Len(strInput) = 0 Then Exit Function
    '999999999---------------------------------------LenB()strInput
    ReDim bTmp(LenB(strInput) - 1) 'Memory length


    'Dim size As Integer = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(strInput) - 1
    ReDim bArray(Len(strInput) - 1) 'String length 

    '999999999=---------------------------------------- CopyMemory(strInput, lPntr, 0)
    CopyMemory(StrPtr(strInput), System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(strInput))
    ' CopyMemory(strInput, lPntr, 0)

    'Examine every second byte
    For lPntr = 0 To UBound(bArray)
        If bTmp(lPntr * 2 + 1) > 0 Then
            'bArray(lPntr) = Asc(Mid$(strInput, lPntr + 1, 1))
            StrToByte = CopyArra(bTmp)   '  StrToByte = System.Array.Copy(strInput, lPntr + 1, 1)
            Exit Function
            Exit Function
        Else
            bArray(lPntr) = bTmp(lPntr * 2)
        End If
    Next lPntr
    StrToByte = CopyArray(bArray)
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).